# Once i get the alert i am not able to add the persons into my database

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
(void)addPersonButton:(id)sender {
            char *error;
            if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &personDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
                if ([nameField.text length] > 0 && [ageField.text length] > 0 ){
                //{NSLog(@"mobile num %@", mobileNumField.text);
                    //NSCharacterSet *decimalSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];

                    //if ([mobileNumField.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:decimalSet].location == NSNotFound) {

                NSString *phoneNum = @"^(\\+91||0)?\\d{10}";

                    NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES  %@", phoneNum];

                    BOOL matches = [test evaluateWithObject:[mobileNumField text]];
                    BOOL valid;
                    if (matches) {
                     sqlite3_stmt *statement;
                     NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM PERSONS"];

                     const char *query_sql = [querySQL UTF8String];

                     if (sqlite3_prepare(personDB, query_sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                     while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                     NSString *mobilenum = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
                         NSLog(@"in DB: %@ and in TF:%@", mobilenum, mobileNumField.text);
                         NSInteger len = [mobileNumField.text length];

                         NSLog(@"len %d",len);
                        // if (len > 10) {
                             NSInteger len1 = len - 10;
                             NSString *string = [mobileNumField.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(len1, 10)];
                         NSRange find = [mobilenum rangeOfString:string];
                         NSLog(@"find length %d",find.length);
                         //}
                         if (find.length) {
                             valid = false;
                             break;
                         }//else {NSLog(@"am in else");
                             valid = true;
                             //break;
                         //}
                     }NSLog(@"am out of while");

                         if (valid) {
                             NSLog(@"am inside valid if");
                             NSLog(@"%@", mobileNumField.text);
                    NSString *insertStmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO PERSONS(NAME,AGE,MOBNUM) values ('%s','%d','%s')" ,[self.nameField.text UTF8String], [self.ageField.text intValue],[self.mobileNumField.text UTF8String]];         
                    const char *insert_stmt = [insertStmt UTF8String];
                             NSLog(@"insertStmt=%@ and insert_stmt = %s",insertStmt,insert_stmt);
                             int flag1 = (sqlite3_prepare(personDB, query_sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK);
                             int flag = (sqlite3_exec(personDB, insert_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK);
                             NSLog(@"flag1 = %d and flag = %d", flag1, flag);

                if (flag) {
                    NSLog(@"Person Added");

                    Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];

                    [person setName:self.nameField.text];
                    [person setAge:[self.ageField.text intValue]];
                    [person setNumber:self.mobileNumField.text];

                    [arrayOfPersons addObject:person];

                    nameField.text = @"";
                    nameField.placeholder = @"Name ";
                    ageField.text = @"";
                    ageField.placeholder = @"Age";
                    mobileNumField.text = @"";            
                }else NSLog(@"person not added");

                         }
                         else {
                             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Already registered with this mobile num" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                             [alert show];
                         }

                     }

                }
                    else {
                        UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Sorry, It's not valid mobile number. Please enter again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

                        [alert1 show];
                    }


                }
                else {

                    UIAlertView *alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Name and Age fields are should not be empty" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                    [alert2 show];
                }
                sqlite3_close(personDB);

            }
        }
```

In the above code am taking mobile number as a primary key, so whenever I registered with same mobile number then it shows the "alert" after getting the alert am giving another mobile number that is not registered before, at that time my SQL query (`sqlite3_exec(personDB, insert_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK`) is does not execute. I didn't understand why my SQL query is not executed. Please give me solution.

Comment: I bet you're trying to update the database in the app bundle. Sorry, you can't, it's readonly.

Comment: No, am creating my own database and inserting values into the DB, before getting alert am getting flag value 1 in my code, whenever get alert after that am getting flag value is 0.

Comment: At last i got the result...., in my program the error is database locked, because after preparing the DB am not finalize or reset the database. Thats why i got the error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable ARC? if no did you release your Alert?

Comment: ya am enable ARC. The remaining two alerts( i.e alert1 and alert2 in my code) are not creating any issues but alert is creating this issue.

Comment: @KishorekumarreddyNimmakayala primary key cannot be null it is not executable

Comment: whatever you saying am accepting but in my code mobile num am not using as a primary key..., but it like act as a unique key..., with use of my own comparison code...., if u don't mind give me your mail id i will fwd my complete code and check that code detail. thank you for giving reply.

Answer (score 0):

NSApplicationSupportDirectory is the one that works best for you, place your DB in NSApplicationSupportDirectory and then have access to the data from there and you can do insert and other operations. :)

Comment: Ok, but my code is actually working good before getting alert...,after getting alert flag value is getting 0 in my code. @Reno Jones

Comment: Because you must be reading the data by then, but not writing, and when there is an insert operation then eventually it breaks up everything. Also your primary key value is null ?

Comment: ya first am reading the data, and comparing the mobile numbers with all my previous mobile numbers(this num are previously added and stored in DB) if that num is not found then it enters into the "if", after entering into the if am writing the code into my DB. if u don't mind give me your mail id i will fwd my complete code and check that code detail. thank you for giving reply.